# Powershell to find specific feature in a list or library

Tags: powershell, guid, features

I have a particular feature which has been orphaned and I no longer have access to re-install it. However it is locked in to three lists that I have in my site collection. I can find it in one of the lists because the list errors and notes the feature in the ULS logs. The other two lists i cannot find, I was hoping there was a way to search the site collection using powershell to see where this particular feature was being used...and i'm not just talking about which web is using it...i need to know what list/library in that web. If it is easier i know which webs contain the feature and could start from there with powershell, i just need to know what code to use to search the lists/libraries for this particular feature GUID.

I'm trying to rid my environment of these orphaned features so that i can successfully patch my farm to SP1, until I remove these it will not let me fully update.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Phil Childs has a some PowerShell scripts that can be helpful (some tweaking may be required in your case) -

- [Removing features from a content database in SharePoint 2010 using PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/06/removing-features-from-content-database.html) (use the -ReportOnly switch to list out the Features)
- [Bulk deactivate feature and remove farm solution in PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/08/bulk-deactivate-feature-and-remove-farm.html)

There are two other tools from CodePlex that can help you manage the installed Features

- [Feature Admin Tool](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/)
- [SharePoint Manager 2010](http://spm.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you for these resources, I have actually been looking over the first link you provided from Phil, looks promising. The tools you provided are what i've been using so far to figure out where it is located. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Features do not have a possible scope of 'List' so the specifics of how each feature affects lists is wholly dependent on what artifacts the feature itself adds.  As such, there is no way to look for lists affected by a particular feature.

Instead, you will need to know what it is specifically that is blocking the upgrade.  If it is an outdated eventreceiver, then you can use [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/22762) to remove it (VERY CAREFULLY and backup the data first).  If it is outdated Content Types then those can be removed by hand.

If really need to get more detailed, you could extract the feature's WSP, rename it to CAB then open it and see exactly what it is doing.  The PowerShell below will copy all WSPs in a farm to a local folder.

```
(PowerShell)

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$solutions = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local.Solutions;
foreach ($solution in $solutions) {
   $solution.SolutionFile.SaveAs("c:\wsp\" + $solution.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was helpful to know and In my research I have been realizing the same truth so it is good to find some extra confirmation on it and ideas.